# Setting a cookie with path value in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, cookies, selenium-webdriver

I am tying to create a cookie with path and domain values using  a selenium cookie class constructor:

```
Cookie newCookie= new Cookie(name, value);
driver.manage().addCookie(newCookie);
```

I am able to get cookie with -

```
cookieSet=driver.manage().getCookies();
```

but when I am trying to do something like,

```
Cookie newCookie= new Cookie(name, value, domain, path, expiry);
driver.manage().addCookie(newCookie);
```

I am able to create cookie , I can see the cookie is added in Firefox cookies,  but when I try to get cookie with -

```
cookieSet=driver.manage().getCookies();
```

it is not getting that particular cookie

Why so?

Answer (score 0):

You can get cookie by it's name and then looking at it, you can check if your cookie is created or not -

```
 driver.manage().getCookieNamed("cookieName");
```

Comment: in my issue , i am adding two cookies one with only name value parameters and another one with path,domain,expiry Date  parameters ,both of them are getting added, in Firefox ->preferences->remove individual cookies. but when i try to access using getCookies() , i am only getting cookie with name value pair and not the  other cookie with path,domain,expiry.  Can it related to Firefox driver,or selenium cookie class related issue ?

Comment: Can you tell me what `driver.manage().getCookieNamed("cookieName");` returns for the other cookie with path, domain, expiry etc?

Comment: If it's returning `null`, means the `path` you're using for the cookie is invalid or non-exists.